# document.getElementById for different "id" values or alternative to this code

Tags: javascript, regex

Actually I'm trying to create an "autosave" system for the content of some "" marked as contenteditable.

DIVS have an structure like his.

```
<div id=test_one contenteditable=true>
<div id=test_other contenteditable=True>
[..]
```

And there's a function like this, that works fine for only one div (when the user stops writing on a div save the data)

```
var timeoutId;
document.getElementById('test_one').addEventListener("input", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {    
          function_to_save();    
    }, 1000);
}, false);
```

The problem is that I try to use this same function for all the divs with a id name that includes the word "test", because all this names are generated dynamically...

I try to use regular expressions what I can't make that work... any idea or alternative code?

Comment: Use `document.querySelelctorAll` and an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to find all the elements you need to attach the event. Then loop through the resulted object, and attach the event.

Comment: Isn't it a better approach using a class specifically for those type of Div? Also using regex and ID isn't efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a nodeList

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='test']");
```

and as the question is marked jQuery

```
var elems = $('[id*='test']');
```

`[id^='test']` will match all ids starting with `test`.
`[id$='test']` will match all ids ending with `test`.
`[id*='test']` will match all ids containing `test`.

With a nodeList you'd have to iterate

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='test']");

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
    elems[i].addEventListener("input", functionName, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks It's very ussefull :)  You save my day ;)